# Initial clusters in Kmeans clustering using mahout

Tags: k-means

I am trying to perform kmeans algorithm on data using . The option that has to be passed while running need a path to initial clusters. Can anyone tell me how can we have initial clusters even before starting the algorithm?

```
bin/mahout kmeans \
    -i <input vectors directory> \
    -c <input clusters directory> \
    -o <output working directory> \
    -k <optional number of initial clusters to sample from input vectors> \
    -dm <DistanceMeasure> \
    -x <maximum number of iterations> \
    -cd <optional convergence delta. Default is 0.5> \
    -ow <overwrite output directory if present>
    -cl <run input vector clustering after computing Canopies>
    -xm <execution method: sequential or mapreduce>
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic to me because it is about how to select among options of a specific program, rather than a theoretical issue how initial clusters might be suggested.

Comment: The final sentence seems like a meaningful conceptual question that can be asked irrespective of software implementation. I think it may be OK to stay.